# Is it necessary to extact the code for all null checking which get from db

Tags: java

Below is my code currently, which will get different object from db to check null,
same code will be used in other methods in same server.

Is it necessary to extract them?

Thanks

```
QualifierKeyEntity qualifierKeyEntity = findKeyById(qualifierValue.getQualifierKeyId());
        if (qualifierKeyEntity == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new QualifierKeyNotFoundException().getMessage(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        // Find scope in db
        Scope scope = scopeService.findByScopeId(qualifierKeyEntity.getScopeEntity().getScopeId());
        if (scope == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ScopeNotFoundException(qualifierKeyEntity.getScopeEntity().getScopeId()).getMessage(),
                    HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        App app = appService.getAppByAppId(appId);
        if (app == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new AppNotFoundException().getMessage(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```